# Android xamarin connect to sql server online like somee

Tags: sql, xamarin, xamarin.android

Is it possible to directly connect to sql database of some or any other hosting site except azure without using web api? just directly connect to sql database. In the other hand i have a website to host there then grab some data to android app develop in xamarin

Thank you

Comment: You cannot directly connect to sql server database directly you need a web service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Xamarin as equal to other C# applications can use, for example, [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/overview)

It allows connecting directly to the SQL DataBase and write your own SQL setences.

> The Entity Framework enables developers to work with data in the form of domain-specific objects and properties, such as customers and customer addresses, without having to concern themselves with the underlying database tables and columns where this data is stored. With the Entity Framework, developers can work at a higher level of abstraction when they deal with data, and can create and maintain data-oriented applications with less code than in traditional applications.

[image: EF]

Comment: i tried to connect using the provided connection string of somee.com but it fails.. workstation id=gevinBySomee.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=changed;pwd=changed;data source=gevinBySomee.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=thesis072717